# Service started with dead intent

Tags: android-service

So basically I have a `Service` that is local to my app. It is only started from one place in the code, where I send it an extra in the starting intent. In the `onStartCommand(Intent, flags, startId)` method, I read the extra via

```
this.searchId = intent.getStringExtra("searchId")
```

now, sometimes the app crash, and the logs show that this line is the culpit, the intent passed in being null, and therefore intent.getStringExtra throwing an NPE.

Question: How can the intent be null? Only I ever start the service, and I specifically create the intent.

Comment: What do you return from `onStartCommand()`?

Comment: Yep, that's the answer. See below. I posted after figuring it out, so I made this a Q&A post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Service can be killed by the system for whatever reasons like power, or memory or just for laughs. When it does, the System wants to know if you'd like your Service restarted when the conditions allow it to run again. The way you describe if you'd like your Service restarted, and how, is via the value you return from onStartCommand. There are four choices

- `START_STICKY` the default option (one that `Service`'s own `onStartCommand` returns) tells the system to restart the service, but without redelivering the Intent that was used to start it. This is what was causing my service to be started with a null intent.
- `START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY` don't actually know what this does, documentation unclear
- `START_NON_STICKY` Once the service is killed for whatever reason, the system shouldn't restart it, but the app itself is responsible for restarting if it needs.
- `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` tells the system to restart the service, and to send it the same intent that was used to start it in the first place. This is what I ended up returning in my service in order to prevent null Intents issues. Now, if my service is killed for some whacked out reason, it is restarted the same way that it was started originally, my onStartCommand sees no difference, and everything goes smooth.

If you are not using the start intents for something useful, then the default `START_STICKY` is just as good. Simply return

```
return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
```